# SQL help to insert unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert the Unique combination of Ticker, Dividend_Pay_Date to another table. If I find duplicate data I need to select only the `Dividend_type_marker_description = 'Final'` row. I am showing example of source data where I have duplicate data for Ticker ABC.

I have noticed `Dividend_type_marker_description = '2nd Interim'` also for same date-ticker combination. But no more than 3 status

[image]

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `row_number()` does what you want:

```
select . . . 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ticker, dividend_pay_rate
                                order by (case when Dividend_type_marker_description = 'Final' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```